# how to generate a fully-connected directed random graph in networkx 2.1?

Tags: random, networkx, directed-graph

I need to generate a random fully-connected directed graph in networkx 2.1 to evaluate the performance of an algorithm of asymmetric traveling salesman problem. for example, generate a graph with 100 nodes, they are fully-connected, the edge weights are assigned randomly. the graph is directed (the edge weight from node i to node j is not necessarily equal to the edge weight from node j to node i)

Wondering whether there is a networkx function to generate this kind of directed graph or some sample code to refer to.

I checked the "directed generators) part in the documentation of networkx 2.1 (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.1/reference/generators.html?highlight=generator#module-networkx.generators.directed), but these generators seem to not meet my requirement.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by random and fully-connected?  I interpret your question as saying every possible edge exists, but the weights assigned are random.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, every possible edge exists, but the weights assigned are random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Networkx has no exactly this kind of generators because it is **very** specific task. So you should construct this graph manually. You can create the complete directed graph:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

N = 7
G = nx.complete_graph(N, nx.DiGraph())
```

and then assign random weights to each graph edge:

```
for (start, end) in G.edges:
    G.edges[start, end]['weight'] = random.random()
```

so you will get exactly the graph you need:

```
G.edges.data('weight')
```

```
OutEdgeDataView([(0, 1, 0.7188354727617898), (1, 0, 0.9755945178178834),  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably several options for how to do this.  Here I just make a list of all the weighted edges with a random weight using `itertools`.  Then I use `add_weighted_edges_from` to create the directed graph.  So it doesn't get too long I only use 3 nodes.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools
import random

G = nx.DiGraph()
weighted_edge_list = [(u,v,random.random()) for u,v in itertools.permutations(range(3),2)]
G.add_weighted_edges_from(weighted_edge_list) 

G.edges(data=True)
> OutEdgeDataView([(0, 1, {'weight': 0.025851202944826346}), (0, 2, {'weight': 0.8067025754602839}), (1, 0, {'weight': 0.7729736390607577}), (1, 2, {'weight': 0.8724493159416196}), (2, 0, {'weight': 0.9049870220916731}), (2, 1, {'weight': 0.9636865700934618})])
```